# Save work into several commits

Tags: git

Most of the time, when doing some work, one ends up with changes that should be saved into different commits.

I am looking for best practices for how to do that in a good way.

Of course, the basic answer is to use `git add -p`.

The problem with that basic answer is that it doesn't enable to test a given state of the repository before committing. Very often, this would mean forgetting to add some imports, or forgetting a dependency between some staged code and some unstaged parts. As a result, a given commit would not pass a build.

Thus I am looking for a way to create several commits, with the ability to run tests for each commit.

The workflows I have tried so far are the following:

#### Workflow 1: commit, stash then test

As long as there is more than 1 commit to do with current changes, repeat:

- `git add -N <new files>      # To mark all new files as potentially stageable`
- `git add -p                  # To add only first commit's changes`
- `git commit`
- `git stash save -k -u`
- run tests
- while tests don't pass

  - `git stash pop`
  - fix code
  - git add relevant changes
  - `git commit --amend --no-edit`
  - `git stash save -k -u`
- `git stash pop`

The main problem I see with this workflow is the fact that it doesn't make a lot of sense to commit something without having tested it, knowing that it is likely to be amended shortly after.

#### Workflow 2: stash, test then commit

As long as there is more than 1 commit to do with current changes, repeat:

- `git add -N <new files>           # To mark all new files as potentially stageable`
- `git add -p                       # To add only first commit's changes`
- `git stash save -k -u             # To remove everything that was not added`
- run tests
- while tests don't pass

  - `git stash pop`
  - fix code
  - git add relevant changes
  - `git stash save -k -u`
- `git commit`
- `git stash pop`

The main problem I find with that workflow, is the fact that `git stash pop` often fails with a **conflict**. That results in having to redo `git add -p` on all the conflict files, which can be very time consuming. This happens among other things when trying to add only part of a new file.

#### The question

Are there other better practices for saving into several commits while testing each one ?

Answer (score 1):

Forget `stash`, use interactive `rebase`. Commit everything as needed and clean up the mess later.

I'd suggest using `git gui` to create the commits, but that's a minor point. After a while I get a list of commits like

```
Implement feature A
Refactor mess B
f A 1
f A 2
f B 3
Improve formatting
f A 4
f B 5
```

where "f A" means "fixup for A". Then I call

```
git rebase -i
```

or maybe

```
git rebase -i HEAD~8
```

get a list of commits and reorder them like

```
Improve formatting
Implement feature A
f A 1
f A 2
f A 4
Refactor mess B
f B 3
f B 5
```

I do this reordering in many small steps, just in case it fails. I use `git diff ORIG_HEAD` in order to verify that the final version stayed the same.

As the last step I change "pick" to "f" (fixup) so that I end up with three commits only.

For running tests on the intermediate steps, you can also use rebase. Just replace "pick" with "e" (edit), so that git stops after each commit (use `git rebase --continue` to continue to the next commit).

When doing such a commit cleanup, I usually run the tests last as they usually pass and, in case they don't, the fix is usually obvious.

When rebasing, be careful not to change commits pushed to a shared repository.

Comment: The interactive rebase has quite a few helpers that automate parts of exactly this workflow: [`--autosquash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase---autosquash) in combination with `git commit --fixup=...` and `git commit --squash=...` and [`--exec`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase--xltcmdgt). The former allows to automatically prepare the todo list while the latter can be used to run tests for example. A failing test would pause the rebase to amend the just produced faulty commit.

Comment: @mmlr Thanks! Good to know, though I usually spend most time with solving problems due to the needed commit reordering, where no tool can help me. So I don't care about `autosquash` (though other may). but `--exec` is nice.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is CI (continuous integration) server. You push as many commits as you want, CI server pulls the branch, checkout commits one by one and run tests on every commit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I see how CI automates the process of running the tests, but in terms of git workflow, I don't see how that's much different from workflow number 1 : if CI server tells you your tests failed on your commit, you have to amend it etc